# How to create Half hemisphere 3D model

Tags: 3d, unity, 3d-meshes, 3d-modeling

I already have an `hemisphere.obj` 3D model. But I'm trying to build a half-hemisphere (quarter sphere) model. How can I do that? What is the easiest way to do that?

Generally, is there any easy way to create 1/n of sphere?

[image]

Comment: No least you can do is create a custom script that handles the logic for (1/n)th of a sphere, but that is not a very easy thing to do.

Comment: do you want it in unity or any particular 3d modeling software?

Comment: Possibly Unity, but matter where. Just want to create a mesh somewhere as an .obj file.

Comment: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ProceduralPrimitives#C.23_-_Sphere possibly modified as needed.

Comment: That's for sphere only. How shall I modify it to get semisphere or say quarter sphere?

Comment: I posted my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024990/how-to-compute-hemisphere-from-a-sphere-code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just need it once, I'd suggest you pick up some basic knowledge of a modelling tool. It's very easy to do in [Blender](http://www.blender.org):

1. Delete the cube that you start with by pressing `DEL`.
2. Create an `UV Sphere` primitive. This will create a sphere with radius 1.0
   (Note: In the lower left corner you can edit the properties (segment/ring count, radius) of the sphere after creation.)
   [image: Blender: Create UV Sphere]
3. Change view to `Front` and zoom in using the mouse wheel:
   [image: Blender: Change view]
4. Press `TAB` to enter edit mode. Press `a` to clear the selection (which is orange).
5. Change the display mode to wireframe (so we can select stuff that would be hidden behind the front surface):
   [image: Blender: Edit wireframe]
6. Press `b` and you'll get a selection rectangle. Select all vertices you want to remove:
   [image: Blender: Select and delete vertices]
7. Press `DEL` and select `Vertices`.
8. For a quarter-sphere: Change view to `Top` like in step 3 and repeat steps 6 and 7.
9. Once you're done editing, hit `TAB` to exit edit mode.
10. Change shading to `Smooth` so you get interpolated normals:
    [image: Blender: Set smooth shading]
11. Select `File -> Export -> Wavefront (.obj)`.

Comment: Awesome answer for a beginner to Blender!

Answer (score 0):

Maya experience here. Use a plane or cube to insect with your object. Use boolean operation like UNION,difference, etc to get this.